# Как разбить js файл на модули?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разделить js код на несколько файлов и импортировать их в этот файл.

У меня есть вот такой js код в одном файле. И я хотел бы разделить его на несколько модулей и экспортировать в главный js файл script.js.

Пробовал делать с помощью инструкций:

```
import moduleName from 'module'
import {  } from "module";
```

Разбил кода на модули 
animation-scroll
open-modal
toggleTabs

Код из модулей отображался в главном js файле script.js, но на сайте переставал работать функционал.

Подскажите, что я не правильно делаю??

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  /*
   * Animation scroll
   **/

  // собираем все якоря; устанавливаем время анимации и количество кадров
  const anchors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]')),
    // animationTime = 300,
    animationTime = 7000,
    // framesCount = 20;
    framesCount = 1200;

  anchors.forEach(function(item) {
    // каждому якорю присваиваем обработчик события
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      // убираем стандартное поведение
      e.preventDefault();

      // для каждого якоря берем соответствующий ему элемент и определяем его координату Y
      let coordY =
        document
          .querySelector(item.getAttribute('href'))
          .getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;

      // запускаем интервал, в котором
      let scroller = setInterval(function() {
        // считаем на сколько скроллить за 1 такт
        let scrollBy = coordY / framesCount;

        // если к-во пикселей для скролла за 1 такт больше расстояния до элемента
        // и дно страницы не достигнуто
        if (
          scrollBy > window.pageYOffset - coordY &&
          window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset < document.body.offsetHeight
        ) {
          // то скроллим на к-во пикселей, которое соответствует одному такту
          window.scrollBy(0, scrollBy);
        } else {
          // иначе добираемся до элемента и выходим из интервала
          window.scrollTo(0, coordY);
          clearInterval(scroller);
        }
        // время интервала равняется частному от времени анимации и к-ва кадров
      }, animationTime / framesCount);
    });
  });

  /*
   * Open modal
   **/

  const page = document.querySelector('.page');
  const orderForm = document.querySelector('.order-form');
  const openModalBtns = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.button[data-action="open-modal"]',
  );
  // const formSubmitBtn = document.querySelector(
  //   '.button[data-action="submit-form"]',
  // );

  openModalBtns.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', handleOpenModal);
  });

  orderForm.addEventListener('submit', handleOrderFormClick);

  function handleOpenModal(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    page.classList.add('show-modal');
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleModalEscPress);
  }

  function handleOrderFormClick(evt) {
    const target = evt.target;
    const nodeName = target.nodeName;

    if (nodeName !== 'BUTTON') return;

    handleSubmit();
    console.log(evt);
  }

  function handleSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    handleCloseModal();
    orderForm.reset();
  }

  function handleCloseModal() {
    page.classList.remove('show-modal');
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleModalEscPress);
  }

  function handleModalEscPress(evt) {
    const key = evt.code;

    if (key !== 'Escape') return;

    handleCloseModal();
  }

  /*
   * Toggle tab buttons and tab panels
   **/

  const tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs');
  const tabsPanels = tabs.querySelectorAll('.tabs__panel');
  const tabsBtns = tabs.querySelectorAll('.tabs__button');

  tabsBtns.forEach(tabsBtn => {
    tabsBtn.addEventListener('click', handleTabsBtnsClick);
  });

  function handleTabsBtnsClick() {
    toggleButtons.call(this);
    toggleTabs.call(this);
  }

  function toggleButtons() {
    //Remove button_checked class from all buttons
    tabsBtns.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('button_checked'));
    //Add button_checked class to current button
    this.classList.add('button_checked');
  }

  function toggleTabs() {
    //Remove tabs__panel_active class from all tabs
    tabsPanels.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove('tabs__panel_active'));
    //Find linked tab by date-tab attribute and add tabs__panel_active' class
    tabs
      .querySelector('.' + this.dataset.tab)
      .classList.add('tabs__panel_active');

    this.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

Comment: В чём смысл? По-хорошему, всё собрать в 1 файл и минимизировать его

Comment: Сейчас все и есть в одном файле. Как видно в примере. Я только начинаю осваивать js и везде встречаю информацию, что необходимо сразу писать код так, чтобы его было потом несложно править (разбивать на модули). Вот и решил попробовать это сделать на проекте с gulp + sass.

Comment: В ссылке @Swartex на mozilla говорится, что полноценная реализация импортов есть в typescript. Мне лень было осваивать webpack, и я использовал typescript. А комментарий InDevX я совсем не понимаю... Минимизация хороша лишь после написания кода, а не в процессе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну для начала нужно использовать какой-то сборщик (webpack/gulp). он будет "билдить" все ваши модули в один файл(бандл) или билд можно настроить как вам нужно, благо конфигурация настраивается. Про webpack читаем здесь https://webpack.js.org/concepts/ . Если проблемы с конфигурацией, то гуглим примеров в интернете полно

Если не хотите использовать сборщики, то есть такой способ https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

но на сайте прямо указано что этот способ только начинает поддерживаться браузерами.

Рекомендую вам всё таки освоить webpack

Comment: Благодарю за информацию. В проекте использую gulp + sass. Я использовал как раз импорт по указанной вами ссылке. Как уже указывал, все импортировалось в один файл, но с дополнительным кодом, который вставляет эта инструкция и у меня ничего не работает. Может сможете еще подскажите, как можно импортировать использую Gulp.

Comment: @ViktorHirenko вы настроили таски для сборки js-кода?

Comment: Я использую готовую сборку [ссылка](https://github.com/luxplanjay/gulp-starter-kit). В ней, наверное, нет таска сборки js модулей в один. Я думал, что модули js это можно делать без тасков.

Comment: @ViktorHirenko а как вы запускаете билд? для того что бы собрать все файлы вам нужно, открыть терминал/консоль в папке проекта, далее написать `npm run start` - это запустит hotreload . Или если вам нужно сбилдить проект для прода то пишем `npm run build` . Все эти команды есть в `package,json`

Comment: Я так все и делаю. Пока решил весь код оставить в одном файле. Это все равно лендинг. Просто хоител разбить логику на компоненты (как css в sass). Позже вернусь к этому вопросу. Благодарю.